# Is this a known issue in gaps between masked raster and spatial polygon in R with mask command?

Tags: raster, gdal, r

This is my codes

raster file: RAD
polygon(shape): ws_sfc

```
RAD.sub <- crop(RAD, extent(ws_sfc))
plot(RAD.sub)
```

[image]

```
RAD.sub <- mask(RAD.sub, ws_sfc)
plot(RAD.sub)
plot(ws_sfc, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Masked raster didn't match with polygon boundaries as shown black arrows.
Is it known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mask` function is doing exactly what is is supposed to do.  `mask` assigns all pixels outside of your polygon area of interest as `NA`.  Specifically, any pixel *center* that falls outside of the polygon gets reassigned `NA`.  You can see that areas specified in your figures are areas where the pixel centroids are outside of the polygon.  To improve the appearance, you can resample the raster to a higher spatial resolution using the `resample` function in the raster package.